# Why does "mvn assembly:single" create a fat jar with just the assemblies and not my code?

Tags: java, maven-2, maven-assembly-plugin

I have a maven project I created with [spring roo](http://www.springsource.org/spring-roo). When I run `mvn assembly:single` I get a fat jar with all the dependencies, but not the actual code I wrote. Here is my maven-assembly-plugin configuration from my pom.xml:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <descriptorRefs>
                    <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                </descriptorRefs>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <mainClass>net.justaprogrammer.poi.cleanser.Cleanser</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The solution is to add the single goal to the package phase of the project life cycle. This means you have to add the following xml under the configuration section:

```
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
```

Answer (score 9):

I will say what you have done are totally enough. Instead of assembly:single, do:

```
mvn clean compile assembly:single
```

And you should be good to go.

Answer (score 2):

Well, `jar-with-dependencies` does exactly what you describe is happening. Why don't you just use `mvn package`?

Comment: jar-**with**-dependencies implies that the jar includes the dependencies in addition to the code I wrote. Also, it doesn't make sense that adding the songle goal to the package phase would change te output produced by the single goal, as I stated in my answer.